# Eloqua delete canvas dependencies using REST API

Tags: python, rest, api, eloqua

I need to delete a big number of canvases and they have filters and segments as dependencies.

I've done an application in Python which sends API calls to get the segments and filters by using a search key but I can't delete them because they are dependencies in canvases.

Is there a way to delete the segments and filters using Eloqua REST API? The segments are also dependencies on some newer canvases that shouldn't be deleted.

Thanks for the help!

Comment: Hi, I'm not sure to understand what you try to achieve because you can't delete a segment or a filter if it is used in a canva.Can you give precise examples ?

Answer (score 0):

If the Campaign Canvas has dependencies, that means the Campaign Canvas is explicitly referenced. In example, the dependent Segment or Filter includes a "Clicked Emails from Campaigns" filer criteria that references the Campaign Canvas.

In this example, in order to remove dependencies, you must edit the criteria to not include the Campaign Canvas you want to delete.